# How to create a video on-demand solution based on IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, smooth-streaming

I went to the [IIS Media services website](http://www.iis.net/media) and got lost with all the good features they have there. What I need is to offer video on-demand (streaming off course) with these features:

- Adaptive streaming
- Support for desktop, iOS and android devices.
- Insert a random short video (advertising) before the actual content.
- Be able to create playlists when necessary.

When reading the material I got confused with a few things:

- I noticed the Playlist extension doesn't support smooth streaming and I couldn't find a way to use playlists there.
- Live smooth streaming has some settings to make it compatible with mobile devices but I couldn't find these options for archived content (what I think they call presentations).
- Windows Media Services has the concept of "Publishing Points" to separate "on-demand content channels", would I have to create multiple websites on IIS to get this kind of "separation"?
- Windows Media Services console and it's API provides real time stats allowing me to know who is playing my content at a given time. I was unable to see it on IIS.

But despite the fact that how confused I am and all those questions in my mind, I appreciate any help in the main topic which is put together the on-demand video channel with it required basic features, specially, mobile support.